# How to hide link url when print in ruby on rails

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, ruby

When I print my report

```
<td><%= link_to (index + 1).to_s, data_report_path(datum.id), target: "_blank" %></td>
```

in print view,I want the index displayed ,say "1".but when I do print,it shows "1(/report_data/1/report)"

I'm using ruby on rails.

**what I have tried:**

**1**.I have added following code in my app/assets/stylesheets/application.css.scss

```
@media print {
    .noprint {display:none !important;}
    a:link:after, a:visited:after {  
      display: none;
      content: "";    
    }
}
```

**2**.add class:'no-print' so the code becomes

```
link_to (index + 1).to_s, data_report_path(datum.id), class:'no-print',target: "_blank"
```

but neither works.

Where should I add & what code should I add to hide this link when print?

Comment: Can you explain what are you trying to do? What do you mean by `instead of just print out index,it also prints the link.how can I get just the index printed?`

Comment: @Mandeep I have edit this part..

Comment: so you mean it's showing href?

Comment: @Mandeep yes,I want only the text displayed without the link

Comment: Quick observation, the class in the link helper is `no-print` but in the css rule it's `noprint`.

Comment: @wen are you using bootstrap?

Comment: @Mandeep no I didn't

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just tested it in [`fiddle`](http://jsfiddle.net/fdn3rLbe/) and it shows up as normal text in print view but when you are using [`bootstrap`](http://jsfiddle.net/fdn3rLbe/1/) or [`foundation`](http://jsfiddle.net/fdn3rLbe/2/) it shows up as you described. Since you are not using bootstrap so i think some other plugin is applying this print style on anchor

```
a[href]::after {
  content: " (" attr(href) ")"
}
```

So you need to override this style in your custom css file. You can do it by

```
@media print {
  a[href]:after {
    content: none !important;
    // use important only if you are not able to override it by normal styling 
  }
}
```